# Creating ER diagram for SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2012, entity-relationship, er-diagram

Is there any tool available in SQL Server (or any free third party tool) which will create ER diagram of the database?

I have 50 over tables and it's painful to create ER diagram one by one adding tables.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to offend you but have you ever tried a Google search with 'ER-Diagram for SQL Server' (lmgtfydotcom-Links are forbidden)?

Or take a look at these links:

https://dataedo.com/blog/creating-database-er-diagram-with-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224825(v=sql.80).aspx

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/94c8c40f-6804-412d-9280-a5d238e4683f/entity-relationship-er-diagram-tools?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: Those are all for SSMS and the current version doesn't support ERD diagrams.

Comment: Thank you for that answer.At that time I couldn't use another payed software.